# Bootstrap - change table layout on mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

So on desktop I want 4 columns with an image above the text like the first image (so col-3), very easy. (I have the image and text in the same col)

[image]

but on mobile I want the icon appear on the left and the text on the right as per the second image.

[image]

i have tried floating the image lleft and the text right but that doesnt work I tried splitting the image and the text but they won't line up properly on all screen sizes if i do.
This feels like it should be so easy but my brain is stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Flex instead of floating divs for the div that contains `col` class

See here an example  - https://playcode.io/995433 (Try to resize the playground viewport to see the mobile layout). I hope this is what you need. I've used BS inline classes for convenience.

Comment: This was great, thanks. I tried using flex on my own but apparently got it wrong, with this example I was able to resolve it. Thanks again. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap align div horizontal to vertical on responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294428/bootstrap-align-div-horizontal-to-vertical-on-responsive) There is your reference

Comment: This is actually the opposite of what I need, going from vertical to horizontal and I am not sure it will work with multiple elements side by side but will try to reverse engineer it, thanks

Comment: am using bootstrap 5 not 3.3 like this example, and can't get the multi-columns to swap from 4 across to the opposite two wide.